# Should I participate in a contest even If I don't want the prize

Tags: physics

I've been preparing this week for a Physics contest a local university is organizing. The prize is a full scholarship for a Physics degree (100% during the 5 years term).

I believe I can win, but the problem is that I do not want to study physics, I want to study Computer Science, yet I want to participate in the contest to achieve a personal win (perhaps for my ego :P).

I'm aware that if I win and decline the prize, it will be given to the 2nd place.

Now, I've been having some problems with my relatives. They say it's time lost for me, that there's no point participating if even if I win I'll decline the prize, etc. Yet I still want to.

What am I doing is wrong, shall I listen to them and not participate?

I'd like to know everyone's opinion because I've been doubting recently whether I should participate or not.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that this site is for academia at the graduate level or higher.  It sounds like you are either an undergraduate or a pre-university student.  Could you confirm this?  In this particular case, I think the question loses most of its relevance if you try to transpose it to the graduate level: there are very few *contests* which result in graduate scholarships, but if there is one and you want to take it -- fine, do so.  Moreover, most university students are adults, so it's not clear why relatives' opinions would be problematic: e.g. just don't tell them you're taking the contest.